# Integrate Drupal in Yii

Tags: drupal, yii

I'm developing a web application in Yii (1.1 & 2.0), now the client wants to integrate WordPress in it so he can manage contents on his own.

So how can I integrate Drupal in Yii and how advanced they are?

Answer (score 1):

Both Drupal and Wordpress are CMS, while Yii is a generic web application framework. You can't integrate Drupal or Wordpress in Yii, that does not make much sense and will probably cause issues. Yii likely expect your application to be structured in a particular way, and neither Drupal or Wordpress will comply with that. What is doable, is to have a Wordpress or Drupal site used for content management but not actually used to display the content to the end user. And Have a Yii application query them via an HTTP based API.

For Drupal, this is doable using the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what your client exactly needs. 
Yii and Wordpress can be integrated in two ways (workflows) :

1. Wordpress under Yii (as an application). 
   This [comprehensive guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/322/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-still-another-approach-using-yii-as-the-router-controller/) goes through it.
2. Yii to power a plugin under wordpress.
   You have no constraints here as wordpress is pretty flexible, you will just need to properly include Yii as you would include any other script when coding a Wordpress plugin.

As far as I understood, your are in the first scenario.